# LayerList Legend onload visible all Layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, legend

I am using LayerList widget and have some problem with Legend when the LayerList is loaded the first time. Actually I have a lot of Group Layers and some of them are turned off but inside the group there are some layers turned on but not visible because the Group Layer is turned off at the beginning.

The problem is the first time when LayerList is loaded, in Legend tab all symbols for all sublayers which are turned on (even on those which Group Layer is turned off and they are not visible on map) are shown.
If I turn on or off (by mouse click) some layer then the legend becomes normal and doesn't have this problem.

Did anyone have the same problem and found a solution?
I try on method onload to refresh the widget or to turn on layer and then turn off programatically but it did not solve the problem